# Getting just the headers for all the messages in 25 threads

Tags: gmail-api

I have 25 thread ids and I'd like to get the `from` header for every message on every one of the threads.

The currently I'm doing a batch get on users.threads, however, this downloads all the message contents and attachments unnecessarily. The benefit though is that this can be completed in one batch API call.

The only way to get just the from header of the messages is to request the messages individually. So one alternative is to do an initial fetch of all the threads and just get the message id fields for each thread. Then do another N set of batch calls to fetch each of the messages. Since threads can have many messages and there is a 100 req limit on each batch call. This could potentially be many requests.

What is more efficient in this case for the gmail API to return? One batch thread call with all the data or many batch message calls?

Comment: the ideal solution seems to be to support the METADATA format on users.threads.get and just return the headers you want but from the docs it doesn't look like thats possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indeed the server supporting threads.get(format=METADATA) would be ideal.

however, barring that I'd just call threads.get() on each thread--if you're only doing it for 25 threads it's not a big deal and threads.get() is pretty efficient--it only returns small body parts not huge attachments (those are only given an attachment ID which can be fetched separately).  then if/when Gmail does provide a format=METADATA for threads.get() it'll be simple to change, don't have to deal with batching, etc.